# PHP AJAX Filter Issues

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, isset

I am trying to make a filter for a website for cars. I would like to be able to filter by exterior color. I use  exterior to represent my color in the database. My UL puts all color from the database into the box and makes each one a induvial check box. Then I have my page that list of all cars through a SELECT * Statement and then I fetch my results through individual echo statements that are wrap and a div. I Do not want to display my exterior colors name next to each car on this page since I am designing a mobile version and trying to keep it clean. However I have tried to list them as induvial  tags and I still get send to a blank page.

```
<ul class="list-group">
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT exterior FROM newcars ORDER BY exterior";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input product_check" name="" value="<?= $row['exterior']; ?>" id="exterior"><?= $row['exterior']; ?>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul>

<div id="test">

        <?php
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM newcars";
          $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
          if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo ("<a href='newcarindex.php?id={$row['id']}'><div class='car'>");
                echo '
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                        <img src="data:image\jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['photo']).'"/>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                ';
                echo "<h2 class=car-name>";
                echo $row['name'];
                echo "</h2>";
                echo "<span class=stock>STOCK#";
                echo $row['stock'];
                echo "</span>";
                echo "<h3 class=car-msrp>";
                echo $row['msrp'];
                echo "</h3>";
                echo "</div></a>";
            }
          } else {
            echo "There are no matching results!";
          }
        ?>
    </div>
```

this then leads into my ajax script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $(".product_check").click(function(){
        $("#loader").show();

        var action = 'data';
        var class = get_filter_text('class');
        var body = get_filter_text('body');
        var exterior = get_filter_text('exterior');

        $.ajax({
          url:'action.php',
          method:'POST',
          data:{action:action,class:class,body:body,exterior:exterior},
          success:function(response){
          $("#test").html(response);
          $("loader").hide();
        }
        });

      });

      function get_filter_text(text_id){
        var filterData = [];
        $('#'+text_id+':checked').each(function(){
          filterData.push($(this).val());
        });
        return filterData;
      }

    });
  </script>
```

and Finally use a action.php page to connect to my database and filter the results

```
include 'dbh.php';

if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM newcars WHERE class !=''";

if(isset($_POST['exterior'])) {
    $exterior = implode("','", $_POST['exterior']);
    $sql .="AND exterior IN('".$exterior."')";
  }

$result = $conn->query($sql);
  $output='';

  if($result->num_rows>0){
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $photo = base64_encode($row['photo']);
    $output .= "<a href='newcarindex.php?id={$row['id']}'>
        <div class='car'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src='data:image\jpeg;base64,{$photo}'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <h2 class='car-name'>{$row['name']}</h2>
            <span class='stock'>STOCK#{$row['stock']}</span>
            <h3 class='car-msrp'>{$row['msrp']}</h3>
        </div></a>";
}
echo $output;
}
  } else {
    echo "There are no comments!";
  }
}
?>
```

The Problem I have is every time i click on a color to filter by my page comes up blank showing no results or errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: echo $output;  you are not returning the output except for else part

Answer (score 0):

just looking at the action.php, upon a successful query, I don't see `$output` being echoed. Is this the complete code for the `action.php`?

````
include 'dbh.php';

if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM newcars WHERE class !=''";

if(isset($_POST['exterior'])) {
    $exterior = implode("','", $_POST['exterior']);
    $sql .="AND exterior IN('".$exterior."')";
  }

$result = $conn->query($sql);
  $output='';

  if($result->num_rows>0){
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $photo = base64_encode($row['photo']);
      $output .= "<a href='newcarindex.php?id={$row['id']}'>
        <div class='car'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src='data:image\jpeg;base64,{$photo}'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <h2 class='car-name'>{$row['name']}</h2>
            <span class='stock'>STOCK#{$row['stock']}</span>
            <h3 class='car-msrp'>{$row['msrp']}</h3>
        </div></a>";
    }
    echo $output;
  } else {
    echo "There are no comments!";
  }
}
?>
```
````

Comment: This is. If I where to echo out the $output what how would I do it?

Comment: I've just added the echo `$output` right after the while block. Sometimes it would also help to use Postman to see if your `action.php` file is working as intended.

Comment: So ive updated it but still running into the same issue. Every time I load the action.php page it just comes up blank?